# SQL Sub Query in Case statement

Tags: sql, subquery, case

I have two tables:

Employee

| Name | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| Gaurav | 2000 |
| John | 5500 |
| Wayne | 6500 |
| Sam | 1000 |

Threshold

| id | MinSalary | Maxsalary | band | Startdate | Enddtl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3000 | Junior | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |
| 2 | 3001 | 5000 | Senior | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |
| 3 | 5001 | 9000 | SupSen | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |
| 4 | 0 | 3100 | Junior | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |
| 5 | 3101 | 5500 | Senior | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |
| 6 | 5501 | 6000 | SupSen | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 |

```
select * from Employee
```

I want to write down a case statement to categorize employees. based on Min salary and Max salary for the latest data.

Comment: Remove the duplicated parts. And instead _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CASE Statement, but you could also achieve the same result by joining directly to your threshold table. I've given examples for both.

I've made assumptions as the expected result has not been specified. It is assumed all salaries have a threshold.

**Case Statement**

```
SELECT
    [Name],
    [Salary],
    CASE
        WHEN [Salary] >= 0 AND [Salary] <= 3000 THEN 'Junior'
        WHEN [Salary] >= 3001 AND [Salary] <= 5000 THEN 'Senior'
        WHEN [Salary] >= 5001 AND [Salary] <= 9000 THEN 'SupSen'
    END SalaryBand
FROM Employee
```

**Joining To The Threshold Table**

You can achieve the same result by joining to the threshold table. Rather than having to update the SQL in the future, the table can be updated instead.

```
SELECT
    e.[Name],
    e.[Salary],
    T.[band]
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Threshold T ON
    e.Salary >= T.MinSalary
    AND e.Salary <= T.MaxSalary
```

**Joining To The Threshold Table (point in time)**

If you have different start and end dates in your threshold table, you can pick the thresholds that are relevant in a point in time by adding a where clause.

```
SELECT
    e.[Name],
    e.[Salary],
    T.[band]
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Threshold T ON
    e.Salary >= T.MinSalary
    AND e.Salary <= T.MaxSalary
WHERE
    '2023-08-01' BETWEEN Startdate AND Enddtl
```